# Scatterplots for subsets of multivariate data [Updated]

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

**Update/Re-write**

There has been a lot of ambiguity over what i'm am trying to do with this question so I have decided to give it a full rewrite. I'm *really* sorry for the confusion. If you want to see the background please see the edit history. I hope things are clearer now..

I have some data made up into the following fashion:

```
datac =
  {
   data1 = RandomReal[1, {7, 3}],
   data2 = RandomReal[1, {13, 3}],
   data3 = RandomReal[1, {19, 3}],
   data4 = RandomReal[1, {16, 3}],
   data5 = RandomReal[1, {5, 3}]
   };
```

`data1` through `data5` are subsets of a multivariate dataset with 3 *independent* variables. `data1`, for example, is composed of 7 individual data points (each with 3 variables).

If I use the following function:

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
pairwisecol[data_, col_] := 
PairwiseScatterPlot[data, 
                      PlotStyle -> col, 
                      DataTicks -> True,  
                      DataLabels -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

I can create a *combined* plot comparing the various subsets. E.g.

```
Show[{pairwisecol[data1, Red], 
      pairwisecol[data2, Blue], 
      pairwisecol[data3, Green],  
      pairwisecol[data4, Purple], 
      pairwisecol[data5, Orange]}]
```

[image]

This curently has the major drawbacks that each subset has to be defined and have a colour explicitly assigned to it. Also, `Show` in this instance overlays all of the `DataTicks` etc, rather than just the elements from the first plot (as is normally the case with `Show[{Plot1,Plot2}]`).

What I'm looking for is a way to use the whole (partitioned) dataset `datac` to generate such a plot/diagram. i.e. something like,

```
Show[pairwisecol[#, Red] & /@ datac]
```

but, with `Red` being replaced by a series of colours to represent each subset (like in the plot shown).

...Alternatively, starting with a 2-level list e.g.

```
datap = RandomReal[1, {60, 3}];
```

and a definition of sublist partitions,

```
parts = {7, 13, 19, 16, 5};
```

or

```
partspos = {[[1;;7]], [[8;;20]], [[21;;39]], [[40;;55]], [[56;;60]]};
```

then defining a function something like:

```
pairwiseP[data_, partlist_] := ...
```

that would partition `datap` into appropriate sublists, create a series of `PairwiseScatterPlot`'s (each with a different plot colour) and then combine them using `Show`.

Note that this example has n = 3 independent variables. I am looking for a method that works for 1 < n < ~20.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: As I see it, you have something like a 4x4 grid of triples of real numbers.  What is to be plotted against what in your scatter plots?

Comment: To rephrase @Michael's query: which variables are dependent, and which ones are independent?

Comment: @0x4A4D, the actual data are part of a simplex so none are truly independent.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `data[[1,ALL,1]]` vs `data[[1,ALL,2]]`...vs `data[[1,All,n]]`... ...`data[[2,All,1]]` vs ... etc.. (so each colour will represent four points). If these data were to be plotted as a single group it would be 16 triples. So in this example i have simply partitioned the data into four subsets (list level 1) that each need to be displayed in a different colour. Does this help?

Comment: I understand `data[[1,All,1]]` vs `data[[1,All,2]]` (an "x" vs. a "y"), but not if it's joined will all `n` (= 3 in this case) components.  Do you mean `data[[1,All, i ]]` vs `data[[1,All, j ]]`, for all `i < j`?  That would give a 4 x 3 array of plots -- would that be right?  In the example plot, the label on the horizontal axis suggests that maybe two values were added -- perhaps?    In theory getting the right array of plots won't be hard to do once I understand what is to be done.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, `data[[1,All, i ]]` vs `data[[1,All, j ]]`, for all `i < j`. Sorry for the confusion (i'm a bit new to this kind of notation). In the actual data example "MgO+FeO" would represent one variable `i`.

Comment: @geordie What would be the criteria to split your data?

Comment: @RodLm as outlined in the update and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with `Ticks` can be solved by fixing `DataRange`. I don't know what is the problem with color specification for You, I hope I have not missunderstood anything:

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]

datap = RandomReal[1, {60, 5}]; (*it works for any n*)
parts = {12, 13, 12, 13, 5}; (* remember that Total@parts == Length@datap *)
colors = {Red, Green, Orange, Blue, Black}; (*or some random, as You like*)

data = Take[datap, {1, 0} + #] & /@ (Partition[Prepend[Accumulate@parts, 0], 2, 1])


Show[
     PairwiseScatterPlot[data[[ #]], DataRanges -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, DataTicks -> True, 
                         PlotStyle -> colors[[ #]], ImageSize -> 500
                        ] & /@ Range[Length@parts]
    ]
```

[image]

I suspect `datap` can be splitted in simpler way but I have blockout now in my head.

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks!

Comment: @geordie there was a mistake in splitting, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still uncertain whether this is what you want.  Just make an array of plots and wrap it in `Grid`.  Fiddle with the options to get axes, dividers, etc. the way you want them.

The way I understand it, the data is really four subsets, each a group of datasets.  For each group, you want to plot one group vs. another group, for each pair of groups, `data[[1, All, i ]]` vs `data[[1, All, j ]]`.  I'm still unsure about the desired coloring.  I've colored the plots by subset (which gives no extra information, except colors are pretty :).  The question states

> The individual colouring of the subsets is what i'm aiming for.

In the example plot, there are mixed colors.  I can only think that the plot is an amalgamation of subsets.  With my current understanding of the question, I don't how to use color to add more to each plot.  I feel like I'm missing something here.

---

Some random data with some structure:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data1 = Map[(# + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 3])^Range[3] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}], {-1}];
Dimensions[data1]
```

Plotting functions:

```
colorFn[subset_] := Hue[subset/4];
plot[subset_, datasets_] := Graphics[{colorFn[subset], Point[#]},
          AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 100] & /@ datasets;
```

Mapping the plotting functions:

```
Grid[
 MapIndexed[plot[First@#2, Thread /@ Subsets[Transpose[#], {2}]] &, data1],
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Plot of 4 pts, 4 groups x 3 subsets]

It's more interesting with 40 points instead of 4:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data1 = Map[(# + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 3])^Range[3] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 40}], {-1}];

Grid[
 MapIndexed[plot[First@#2, Thread /@ Subsets[Transpose@#, {2}]] &, data1],
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Plot of 40 pts, 4 groups x 3 subsets]

---

Just to show the data is being processed as indicated:

```
foo = MapIndexed[Thread /@ Subsets[Transpose@#, {2}] &, data1];
foo[[1, 1]] == Transpose@{data1[[1, All, 1]], data1[[1, All, 2]]}
foo[[1, 2]] == Transpose@{data1[[1, All, 1]], data1[[1, All, 3]]}
foo[[1, 3]] == Transpose@{data1[[1, All, 2]], data1[[1, All, 3]]}
(* etc. *)
```

> ```
> True
> True
> True
> ```

Comment: @geordie  Is this on target or is it wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and effort!... see my edit above.