# PairwiseScatterPlot with histograms along the diagonal

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

The built-in function `PairwiseScatterPlot` has been discussed for example here: [Scatterplots for subsets of multivariate data [Updated]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26595/scatterplots-for-subsets-of-multivariate-data-updated/).
However, I find it not very informative to plot the identity function along the diagonal of the matrix of plots: do you guys know how to plot a more informative histogram instead? Also, it is superfluous to plot the entries above the diagonal.

Here is an example:

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]
data = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1/2, -2/3}, {1/2, 5, 2}, {-2/3, 2, 20}}], 10^3];
PairwiseScatterPlot[data, DataTicks -> Automatic, DataLabels -> {"var1", "var2", "var3"}]
```

[image]

UPDATE:
I have improved the code a user wrote as a possible solution (unfortunately that user deleted that entry). Basically I have fixed a bug and the labels. Here is what it does:

```
pspF3 = With[{dt = #, ca = ConstantArray[Null, {#, #} &@Dimensions[#][[2]]],
opts = Sequence[AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]}, 
GraphicsGrid[ReplacePart[ca, {{i_, i_} :> Histogram[dt[[All, i]], Automatic, "PDF", opts, 
     If[i == Dimensions[dt][[2]], FrameLabel -> {"var" <> ToString[i], None}, FrameLabel -> None],
PlotRange -> All, Ticks -> Automatic],
{i_, j_} /; i > j :> ListPlot[dt[[All, {j, i}]], opts,
Which[i == Dimensions[dt][[2]] && j > 1, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {"var" <> ToString[j], None}}, i == Dimensions[dt][[2]] && j == 1, FrameLabel -> {{"var" <> ToString[i], None}, {"var" <> ToString[j], None}}, i > 1 && j == 1, FrameLabel -> {{"var" <> ToString[i], None}, {None, None}}, i > j, FrameLabel -> {None, None}],
RotateLabel -> True,PlotRange -> All]}], ImageSize -> 600]] &;
pspF3@data
```

[image]

However, the ticks are not aligned and the labels of the ticks are repeated when not necessary (they should appear only at the very bottom and on the left). Also, the size of the various frames is not constant and ideally there should not be gaps. `PairwiseScatterPlot` does all this automatically. Can you improve on this solution?

Comment: One approach is to build your own grid of plots based on `GraphicsGrid` or `Grid`.  Reproduce the six off-diagonal plots using `ListPlot`, and use `Histogram` or whatever else you like for the three diagonal plots.

Answer (score 11):

**Update 3:** Using the function `pwScatterPlot` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200988/125)

```
ClearAll[addHistograms, pwScatterPlot]       
addHistograms = Module[{diag = Diagonal[Partition[Cases[#, {dir_, ___Point} :> dir, All], 
    Round @ PlotRange[#][[1, 2]]]]}, 
 # /. {c : Alternatives @@ diag, p__Point} :> Module[{xy = Cases[{p}, Point[x_] :> x]}, 
   Inset[Histogram[xy[[All, 1]], ChartStyle->c, AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> False], 
     Min /@ Transpose@xy, {Left, Bottom}, {.9, .9}]]] &; 

Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
pwScatterPlot = addHistograms @* PairwiseScatterPlot;
```

To use this function on an input data with `n` series we need to use an n-by-n matrix of styles where the diagonal entries are different from off-diagonal entries.

```
data2 = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 1, 2}, 
    {{1, 1/2, 1/3}, {1/2, 2, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 3}}], 10^3];
labels2 = "var" <> ToString[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
colors2 = {{Red, Blue, Green}, {Blue, Orange, Magenta}, {Green, Magenta, Purple}};

pwScatterPlot[data2, DataSpacing -> .1, DataTicks -> Automatic, 
   DataLabels -> labels2, ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> colors2]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
pspF = With[{dt=#,ca=ConstantArray[1,{#,#}&@Dimensions[#][[2]]],
             opts=Sequence[Axes->False,AspectRatio->1]},
           Grid[ReplacePart[ca, {{i_,i_}:>Histogram[dt[[All,i]],opts],
                {i_,j_}:>ListPlot[dt[[All,{i,j}]],opts]}],
               Dividers->All]]&;

 data1 = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}], 10^2];
 pspF@data1
```

[image]

```
data2 = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0,0}, 
                   {{1, 1/2,1/3}, {1/2, 2,1/3},{1/3,1/3,3}}], 10^3];

pspF@data2
```

[image]

**Update 1:**  Using `DensityHistogram` with the option `Method -> {"DistributionAxes"->True}`:

```
dhF=With[{dt=#,ca=ConstantArray[1,{#,#}&@Dimensions[#][[2]]],
          opts=Sequence[Axes->False,AspectRatio->1]},
       Grid[ReplacePart[ca, {{i_,i_}:>Histogram[dt[[All,i]],opts],
            {i_,j_}:>DensityHistogram[dt[[All,{i,j}]],opts,
                      Frame->False,Method->{"DistributionAxes"->True},
                      ChartElementFunction->"Point"]}],
            Dividers->All]]&; 

data2 = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0,0},
                   {{1, 1/2,1/3}, {1/2, 2,1/3},{1/3,1/3,3}}], 10^3];

dhF@data2
```

[image]

Note: You can also use `"BoxWhisker"`, `"Histogram"` or `"SmoothHistogram"` as the setting for the suboption `"DistributionAxes"`.

**Update 2:** To include `PlotLabels`, `FrameLabels`, `FrameTicks` etc, add these options to `Histogram` and/or to `ListPlot`:

```
pspF2 = With[{dt = #, ca = ConstantArray[1, {#, #} &@Dimensions[#][[2]]], 
     pr = Through[{Min, Max}[#]], opts = Sequence[AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]}, 
    Grid[ReplacePart[ca, 
        {{i_, i_} :> Histogram[dt[[All, i]], Automatic, "Count", opts, 
         PlotRange -> {pr, Automatic},
         FrameLabel -> {{"Count", None}, {"var" <> ToString[i], None}},
         PlotLabel -> ("var" <> ToString[i])], {i_, j_} :> 
        ListPlot[dt[[All, {i, j}]], opts, PlotRange -> {pr, pr}, 
         FrameLabel -> {{"var" <> ToString[i], None}, {"var" <> ToString[j], None}}, 
         PlotLabel -> ("var" <> ToString[i] <> "     versus   var" <> 
            ToString[j])]}], Dividers -> All]] &;

data2 = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 1, 2}, 
          {{1, 1/2, 1/3}, {1/2, 2, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 3}}], 10^3];

pspF2@data2
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to also include DataLabels and DataTicks?

Comment: @Valerio, please see the update.

Comment: thanks but the labels should appear only on the outer frames and so the numbers associated with the ticks (see my updated plot). Also, if I test `pspF2` with `data` of my example (I've changed the covariance matrix to make obvious which is `var1` and which is `var2`) I get the wrong ordering, that is the columns do not have the same variables for the various x-axes: to have the right ordering I have to transpose the matrix.

Comment: @Valerio, just saw your update with a specific example of what you need. I am afraid we need a more elaborate  function than pspF to get a full-fledged trellis display like the example in the linked article. Deleting for now until I find a better approach.

Comment: I have only recently begun to study this topic. Can you please tell me what these histograms show and how they are built from two data sets?

Answer (score 2):

Using the function `VariableDependenceGrid` from the package ["MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m):

```
data = RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1/2, -2/3}, {1/2, 5, 2}, {-2/3, 2, 20}}], 10^3];
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m"]
VariableDependenceGrid[data, "var" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[3]]
```

[image]

(See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200973/34008).)

Comment: I have only recently begun to study this topic. Can you please tell me what these histograms show and how they are built from two data sets?

Comment: @dtn Thank you for your interest! I will do that in the next few days…