# Pairwise Scatter Plots with Histograms and Correlations

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics, visualization

Has anybody written a function which can scatter plot data with histograms and correlations? Here is [an example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html) form MATLAB. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/pairwisescatterplot-with-histograms-along-the-diagonal) is related but does not print correlations. [R](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl/r/scatmat.e.html) has a similar function. Similar function in Mathematica would help new users like me.

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate: [PairwiseScatterPlot with histograms along the diagonal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69713/125)

Comment: @ kglr, thank you for the link to your related answer. Going to update question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
trellisPlot[data, DataTicks -> Automatic, DataSpacing->.1, DataLabels -> labels, 
      ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> colors]
```

[image]

The picture above is produced in two steps: First the function `pwScatterPlot` is used to produce a scatter plot with histograms on the diagonal, then we add linear fits and correlations using the function `addFitsAndCorrelations` (both functions defined below.) The function `trellisPlot` is the composition of `addFitsAndCorrelations` and ``pwScatterPlot`.

We combine `PairwiseScatterPlot` from the `` "StatisticalPlots`" `` package with some post-processing steps to get a function that takes the same argument and options as `PairwiseScatterPlot` and gives histograms on the diagonal of the panel.

The setting for the `PlotStyle` option should be an n-by-n matrix of directives (where n is the number of series in the input data) with diagonal entries different from off-diagonal ones.

```
ClearAll[addHistograms, pwScatterPlot] 
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]      
addHistograms = Module[{diag = Diagonal[Partition[Cases[#, {dir_, ___Point} :> dir, All],  
      Round @ PlotRange[#][[1, 2]]]]}, 
  # /. {c : Alternatives@@diag, p__Point} :> Module[{xy = Cases[{p}, Point[x_] :> x]},
   Inset[Histogram[xy[[All, 1]], ChartStyle->c, AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio, Axes->False],
     Min /@ Transpose @ xy, {Left, Bottom}, {.9, .9}]]] &; 

pwScatterPlot = addHistograms @* PairwiseScatterPlot;
```

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 5], {500, 5}].RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5, 5}];
labels = StringTake[RandomWord["Noun", 5], 4];
```

One possible way to produce a matrix of styles with diagonal entries different from off-diagonal ones:

```
mat = # + Transpose[UpperTriangularize[#, 1]] & @ 
      PadLeft[TakeList[Range[# + (# - 1) #/2], Reverse@Range[#]]] &;
colors = Map[ColorData[97], mat[Dimensions[data][[2]]], {-1}];

pwScatterPlot[data, DataTicks -> Automatic, 
   DataLabels -> labels, ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> colors]
```

[image]

With another layer of post-processing we can add linear fit lines and texts:

```
ClearAll[addFitsAndCorrelations, trellisPlot]
addFitsAndCorrelations = # /. {dir_, p__Point} :> 
  Module[{xy = Cases[{p}, Point[x_] :> x]}, {dir, p, 
   Text[Style[Round[Correlation @@ Transpose[xy], .001], Black, FontSize -> Scaled[.025]], 
       Offset[{5, -15}, Floor[Min /@ Transpose[xy] + {0, 1}]], Left], 
   First @ Plot[Evaluate @ LinearModelFit[xy, t, t][t],
     {t, Min[xy[[All, 1]]], Max[xy[[All, 1]]]}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]}] &;

trellisPlot = addFitsAndCorrelations @* pwScatterPlot;

trellisPlot[data, DataTicks -> Automatic, DataLabels -> labels, 
  ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> colors]
```

> picture at the top

Comment: Superb answer Kglr. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the function `VariableDependenceGrid` from the package ["MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m).

```
?VariableDependenceGrid
```

> "VariableDependenceGrid[data_?MatrixQ,columnNames,opts] makes a grid with variable dependence plots."

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m"]

wineData = (Flatten@*List) @@@ ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "WineQuality"}, "Data"];
wineColumnNames = (Flatten@*List) @@ ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "WineQuality"}, "VariableDescriptions"];

VariableDependenceGrid[RandomSample[wineData, 200][[All, 1 ;; -1 ;; 3]], wineColumnNames[[1 ;; -1 ;; 3]]]
```

[image]

The function `VariableDependenceGrid` also produces plots of dependencies with categorical variables and it also works over `Dataset` objects. Here is an example:

```
titanicData = (Flatten@*List) @@@ ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "Data"];
titanicColumnNames = (Flatten@*List) @@ ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "VariableDescriptions"];

dsTitanic = Dataset[titanicData][All, AssociationThread[titanicColumnNames -> #] &];

VariableDependenceGrid[dsTitanic]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Anton, thank you.

Comment: @DestinationLess_Traveller No problem! You might also be interested in this repository: [MathematicaVsR](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaVsR).