# Scatter plot matrix in older version of Mathematica

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, visualization, inequalities

I need to plot a *similar* graph of a function [[Scatter plot matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot#Scatter%20plot%20matrices)]:

[image]

For:

$f(x,y,z,t) \rightarrow x^2 + y^3 + z^2 + t^2 ≤ 1,x + y - z = t^2$

*But, I work in older version of Mathematica - 12.0*

My considerations:

1. build a dataset that satisfy a given inequalities with help `FindInstance`
2. distribute them in pairs
3. place charts in the table using the `Show` command or equivalent

**Issue:** The resulting plots are discrete and the `FindInstance` command is slow with a large number of points. Are there easier ways to get continuous *scatter plot matrix*?

```
FindInstance[x^2 + y^3 + z^2 + t^2 <= 1 && x + y - z == t^2, {x, y, z, t}, Reals,5] // N
```

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/pairwisescatterplot-with-histograms-along-the-diagonal.

Comment: @JimB thank you very much! I will try to study the material

Comment: Instead of FindInstances you could use the following faster code: `sol=Solve[{y==y0,t==t0,x^2+y^3+z^2+t^2==1-a0,x+y-z==t^2},{x,y,z,t}]; randomSolution:=Block[{a0=RandomReal[{0,1}],y0=RandomReal[{-1,1}],t0=RandomReal[{-1,1}]},
sol]; Flatten[Select[Table[randomSolution,100],FreeQ[#,Complex]&],1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we try to provide the 3D version of scatter plot.

```
Clear[cond, reg, pts];
SeedRandom[3];
cond = Resolve[
   Exists[t, x^2 + y^3 + z^2 + t^2 <= 1 && x + y - z == t^2], Reals];
reg = ImplicitRegion[cond, {x, y, z}];
pts = RandomPoint[
   RegionIntersection[reg, Cuboid[-10 {1, 1, 1}, 10 {1, 1, 1}]], 50];
ListPointPlot3D[{pts, 
  TranslationTransform[{0, 0, -10}]@ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 0}]@pts, 
  TranslationTransform[{0, -10, 0}]@ScalingTransform[{1, 0, 1}]@pts, 
  TranslationTransform[{-10, 0, 0}]@ScalingTransform[{0, 1, 1}]@pts}, 
 ViewPoint -> {5, 4, 3}, BoxRatios -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[Large], Blue], 
   Darker@Green, Darker@Yellow, Darker@Red}, 
 AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}, 
 Boxed -> {Front, Bottom, Left}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]